# Using a loop to generate lists by column of a pd.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and wondering if there was a way to use a loop to generate a set of lists, by column name, from a pandas.dataframe. The pd.dataframe(s) were generated by importing .xlsx files using pd.read.excel, and I'm now trying to avoid spending hours writing what I think may be redundant code.

To give an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6,7,8]
c=["a","b","c","d"]
df=pd.DataFrame({'b':b,'c':c}, index=a)
```

Any ideas about how I'd go about setting up and running a loop to get the following outputs:

column b within df to an individual list variable named b
and the same for c

rather than manually coding it all using .tolist()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your expected output:  a dataframe _is_ a set of lists by column name, except that the lists are actually numpy arrays and the column names are part of an index. I am not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Expected output is a series of lists, with names matching the columns. I hadn't realised that it could all be put into a data dictionary and called back from within that, which BernardL explains below.

I'll update the above regardless to reflect this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your columns and store them into a dict and then access them by column name.

```
empty_dict = {}

for col in df.columns:
    empty_dict[col] = list(df[col])

empty_dict['b']
```

I am assuming you want to extract a list of values from the dataframe column by name.

Comment: Thank you for that! I hadn't realised that lists could be stored within, and called back, from within a dictionary.

Comment: Glad it helped, dictionaries are really useful when you want to assign data to a key rather than assign it to a variable. If it solved your problem, please accept this as an answer by ticking the grey tick under the vote button.

Answer (score 1):

[`.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) converts a dataframe to a dictionary.  There are different output types, but to create lists for each column use the `list` type.

```
>>> df.to_dict('list') 
{'b': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```